# How can you force the browser to download an xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, download

This is my problem.
I load xml from my database and push it to the client using code.
But the problem is that the browser automatically opens that xml instead of offering it as a download.

Is there a way to force your browser to download that file and not showing it?

I'm working in a C#, Asp.net environment (with IIS7).

Thx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
protected void DisplayDownloadDialog()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader(
        "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "filename.xml"));

    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    Response.WriteFile("FilePath");
    Response.End();
}
```

This will force to download the file and not display in the browser.

> This will work for any file types
>   without requiring to specify any
>   special MIME type.

Comment: I have a problem that method is not working for the very first time downloading.. but start from 2nd time onwards, it is working fine.. the first time, instead of the `filename` it is displaying the page name`test1`.. any idea why??

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in this article: http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=8

The key is in this line:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a content-disposition: attachment header.