# How to save files on local drive using File.WriteAllText?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file, download

I'm creating and saving an xml file using the following code:

```
File.WriteAllText("D:\\55_SEPA_30-04-2017.xml", strXMLGenerate);
```

The problem is that the created file saving on server folder not in local drive.
How can I save the file anywhere on local drive path. Is there any way to save the file automatically in local "Download" folder?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Edit:
I'm using File.WriteAllText for creating and saving file for an Ajax call.
In a Ajax calling/ static method the Response.Write/ Response.End() is not supported.
So my question is nowhere duplicate with the mentioned question. Please take a look on it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Asp.net write file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client)

Comment: It is not duplicate with the mentioned question @ Naveen Gogineni

Comment: Usually people don't want to save the xml to a file.  The normal solution is to use a memorystream so you do not need to save to file.

Comment: I need to to save the xml file to my local drive @jdweng

Comment: Be careful of which folder you save data in. Download folder are only accessible to current user.  If file is need by multiple users than pick a folder that all user have credentials to read.

Comment: You cannot save files on local drive using `File.WriteAllText()` or any other C# function. This could be made with some JavaScript as well. Would you care for a such approach?

Comment: From the looks of it, I would say you are trying to save a file to the Client machine using server side code. That is not possible. The only way to do is sending file as a response and letting the browser download it for you.

Comment: Correct. Could you please tell me the process to do it? @ brainless coder

Answer (score 1):

You can't download file through Ajax. Because of security concerns, JavaScript cannot save files directly to a user's computer.

Comment: So what is the way to save the file in a static method?

Comment: It looks like you are using Webmethod with static function. You can't serve file from static method because Response object is not available in static function. The only way is to send file as a response and let the browser download it.

Comment: Could you mention the C# code to "send file as a response"?

Comment: Please check the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913027/how-can-you-force-the-browser-to-download-an-xml-file