# C# Download Files saved on my server Options

Tags: c#, file, download

I Have this code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DownLoad")
        {

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename =" + 
           e.CommandArgument);

Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")+e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

The code works but it opens .txt document and .pdf documents and displays them in the web browser.  If I download a .csv or.doc file I am prompted to save the document or open it.  I would like to have the save or open option for all files that are downloaded.

Comment: See if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913027/how-can-you-force-the-browser-to-download-an-xml-file

Comment: Sorry no change it still opens in the browser